# Error Message : illegal character JavsScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Student Name</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="sname" required>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Course</td>
        <td>
          <select id="course" required>
            <option value="Python">Python</option>
            <option value="Java">Java</option>
            <option value="Oracle">Oracle</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="button" value="Register" id="submit" onclick="display()">
    <div id="greet"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
function display(){
    var name = document.getElementById("sname")
    var subject = document.getElementById("course")
    var greet = document.getElementById("greet")
    if(!name.value){
        greet.innerHTML = "Name cannot be empty"
    } else {
        greet.innerHTML = `Hi, ${name.value}. You have successfully registered for the ${subject.value} course.`
    }
    return false
}
```

I want to pass the test cases of online platform judge
but It is throwing the error Error Message : illegal character
But according to me the code is correct. Please help to understand way I am getting this error.

Comment: Your JavaScript code works properly. Could you try moving `<script src="script.js"></script>` to right before `</body>` instead of inside `<head></head>`?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I did as you instructed yet I am getting the same error.

Comment: And please use `.textContent` instead of `.innerHTML`

Comment: What did you input in the `<input type="text">`?

Comment: <input type="text"> is for the user to write his name.

Comment: Try these: 1) `.innerHTML` -> `.textContent` / 2) `var` -> `const` / 3) Remove `return false`

Comment: It seems to be working OK when I test it. Can you try rewrite the JS code from scratch? There could be something strange going on with the text if you've copied some of it and pasted it in.

Comment: Yes I had pasted the code from my code editor. I will rewrite the code

Comment: Its working as expected for me.